# Logout a user without req object Passport js

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js, cookie-session

I am using [Passport js](http://passportjs.org/) with [Express js](https://expressjs.com/). In my application, I need a functionality that a user should be logged out from the server if he/she is idle for a certain time.

But the problem is it requires `req` (request) object in order to logout a user. How can I logout a user without `req` object.

Note: I am using [cookie-session](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-session) for the persistent session.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but in case anyone else stumbles on this as I did:

If you require logging out with `req`, which is only available on the server, create a route that handles the logout functionality. Then when you need to log out on the client, redirect them to the logout route. (This is often achieved with something like `router.push`).

Since you're using `cookie-session`, you can also delete the cookie instead. You will still want to redirect somewhere after, such as a "you've been logged out" page.